# Trigger Issue : ORA-00905: missing keyword

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I am trying to insert a record into a another table (**tableb**) once a certain condition is met after an insert into a certain table (**tablea**)
So i have created a trigger that checks does the above,
condition : after inserting into tablea, check whether the sum of price in tablea is greater than a certain value, if it is, then insert the tino into tableb.

Script below will recreate the issue i am currently facing.. Need another paid of eyes on this.

```
-- create the tables
CREATE TABLE tablea
(
   tino NUMBER not null,
   price VARCHAR2(200),
   dated date
)
partition by range (DATED)
(
 partition PART_201608 values less than (TO_DATE(' 2016-09-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')),
partition PART_201609 values less than (TO_DATE(' 2016-10-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')),
partition PART_201610 values less than (TO_DATE(' 2016-11-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))
)

--INSERT VALUES
 INSERT INTO tablea (tino,price,dated)VALUES('1234567',10,SYSDATE);
  COMMIT;
  INSERT INTO tablea (tino,price,dated)VALUES('1234560',20,SYSDATE);
  COMMIT;
   -- create table table which once condition is met,, data is written into
 CREATE TABLE tableb(tino number);


-- CREATE THE TRIGGER
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg1
AFTER INSERT
ON tablea
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
v_price NUMBER;
v_partition VARCHAR2(20) := 'PART_'||TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYYMM');
v_tino VARCHAR2(20) := :NEW.tino;
sql_smt VARCHAR2(1000) := '';

BEGIN
  sql_smt :='
      SELECT SUM(price) price INTO v_price
      FROM tablea PARTITION('||v_partition||')
       WHERE tino = '||''''||v_tino||''''||'';

 BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_smt;
   EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('QUERY='|| sql_smt);
 END;

--DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PRICE  =' || v_price);

 IF v_price >= 15 THEN
   INSERT INTO tableb (tino) VALUES (v_tino);
   COMMIT;
  END IF; 
 END;
  -- test the trigger 
   INSERT INTO tablea(tino,price,dated) VALUES('1234567',10,sysdate);
  COMMIT;
```

Should return an ORA-00905: missing keyword

```
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
```

Returns :

```
SELECT SUM(price) price INTO v_price
FROM tablea PARTITION(PART_201609)
WHERE tino = '1234567'
```

Which should ran with no issues

Any pointers??

Comment: You probably can't.  A trigger on A cannot generally query A without getting a mutating trigger error (which it sounds like you are getting in the comments to the answer below).  You should never explicitly specify a partition name unless you happen to have a manually partitioned table.  Just use the predicate and let Oracle figure out the partition.  That eliminates the need to do dynamic SQL.  If you want a declarative solution, a fast-refreshed materialized view with a constraint would be a much better idea than using a trigger plus it would work in a multiuser system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INTO v_price` should be part of the `execute immediate` statement, not part of the dynamic SQL.

btw I think

```
WHERE tino = '||''''||v_tino||''''||'';
```

can be simplified to

```
WHERE tino = '''||v_tino||'''';
```

Or even better,

```
WHERE tino = :tino';
```

with `v_tino` passed as a bind variable with something like

```
execute immediate xyz into v_price using v_tino;
```

Comment: `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_smt INTO v_price;
      EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('QUERY  =' || sql_smt);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PRICE  =' ||v_price);  `                Thanks Will, but it now returns ORA-04091: table TABLEA is mutating, trigger/function may not see it.    Doesnt seen to execute from there as PRICE is null

Comment: I missed that part when looking at your syntax issue. A row-level trigger can't query its own table.

Comment: so what other option do i have here